# Is it mandatory to explicitly mention region name while creating AmazonS3Client to access a file from a bucket in china region?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to access a public file from S3 bucket in china region. Is it mandatory to mention region while creating AmazonS3Client for china region?

Answer (score 0):

I think know because the bucket name is global, so there is no need to explicitly mention the Region while creating the S3Client.

Comment: If I don't mention region name, my service is not able to retrieve the file.
Maybe because it looks that into default aws-region. I am trying by giving the region name in S3 client. Will let you know if that works.

Comment: is it throwing any error?Specified key doesn't exist. You can debug your app if you are working from local environment. Or you can give the region name explicitly. `AmazonS3 client = new AmazonS3Client();client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.fromName(region)));`

Comment: Your assumption is incorrect, @VaisakhPS.  The China regions are in a separate partition of AWS.  The bucket names there are not global elsewhere, so buckets in China can't be resolved to a location by consulting other regions outside.

Comment: you are right @Michael-sqlbot . Thanks for the information.

Comment: I added region to S3Client and it started working. Thanks